# How to secure css and js files means end user could not download our css and js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I designed one website but I don't want to give access to end user to download my css and js files.
because If I designed one website so anybody can stolen my design by downloading my css and js files.
So is there any mechanism for secure our css and js files?

Comment: The answer is NO

Comment: Nope. But then, it's usually very unlikely anybody would want to steal your CSS and JS files.

Comment: Try minify your files just to make it harder to read. Another cents from me.

Comment: minify you codes and check hosted url match with yours in many places of your scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by not download them? You can't. It's the same reason you can't secure an image on website. If someone can see it, they can copy it. When anyone goes to your site, they download a copy of your .css

Comment: If your front end skills are **that good**, you will not have to worry about protecting your web-assets, you will do just fine...

Comment: Thanks to all........all suggestions are very much appreciated..and this is very much usefull for me.

Comment: http://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/391_checkboxes/demo.html

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Your-Website-Indexed-by-Google

Comment: http://whitechristmas.adeveloper.ro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For javascript I would suggest you to use Base62 encoding.
This will also reduce the size and thus boost the performance since there will be less loading time

You can do base 62 encoding [here](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

Other than that you cannot host your javascript file into an non downloadable form!!
Same goes with CSS too.
Once someone enters the full link the css/js files will be shown. All the files be available in the clien machine!!

To put up a plain straight answer to your question, the answer is **NO**

Answer (score 3):

There is not really any way to secure your CSS and JS from being downloaded as the users browser needs to download these files.

One technique which is normally used to reduce CSS and JS file sizes is minification. Although it does not secure the files as such, it makes JS far harder to understand when you choose to mangle the variable names.

[Online JS minifier to try out](http://jscompress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Browser need to read your css file and js file. If browser can read then user can read also. You can minify your codes only e.g http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ and also you can add copyright comment blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In order for visitors to see and use your site, they will have to download the necessary styles and scripts.

You can compress and obfuscate your code of course (the former actually benefits the end-user), but that's the best you can do; it won't stop someone from ripping it and using it as-is for their own nefarious purposes.

Now, your code is technically copyrighted; if you find someone who infringed on this copyright and they're using either a literal copy or a substantial part of your original work, you could theoretically sue them. Whether this is a viable approach is a tough question to answer and you will need someone with at least some kind of law degree and/or experience in this field.

Personally I would say that your chances of successful legal retribution are low, but so is the chance of someone stealing your code and profiting from it.